# Int cannot be dereferenced (arrays)

Tags: java, arrays, bluej

I'm using BlueJ. This is the code that's giving me the error.

```
public void printBackwards() {
    int count = 5;

    for (count = 5; count < holiday.length; count--) // Error: int cannot be dereferenced
    {
        System.out.println(holiday[count]);
        count++;
    }
```

This is the global array I'm working with.

```
String [] holiday = new String [] {"St Paddy's Day", "Spring Break", "Christmas Break", "Easter", "Independence Day"};
```

Anyone know what is causing the error? Thank you very much.

Comment: There is no way that error happens there.

Comment: The code you've provided compiles fine.

Comment: But won't run, as it generates a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: And `count--` and `count++` in the same loop?

Comment: Sorry guys, I put the comment at the wrong part of the code. I've moved it up one line. My apologies.

Comment: And `holiday` is most definitely pointing the global variable, and not some other local/scope variable that isn't an array?

Comment: The comment doesn't change anything. Voting to close as unreproduceable.

Comment: The for loop will never execute,as the condition returns false in the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

try this it works :

```
class printBack {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int count;
    String [] holiday = new String [] {"St Paddy's Day", "Spring Break", "Christmas Break", "Easter", "Independence Day"};

    for (count = 0; count < holiday.length; count++) 
    {
        System.out.println(holiday[holiday.length-count-1]); // Error: int cannot be dereferenced
    }
}
}
```

OUTPUT :

```
Independence Day
Easter
Christmas Break
Spring Break
St Paddy's Day
```